# How to use Rselenium on a linux server

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, shiny-server

I have set up a shiny server on AWS to deploy a shiny app I have developed. The app uses  webscraping to gather its data and so uses the RSelenium package to create the webdriver needed to scrape the web. The app works when run on a local windows machine that can open up a Firefox browser, but it is beyond my knowledge to get it to worker on an ubuntu server. Firefox and all necessary Rpackages should be installed on the server

Here is the code that is initially run. It is the first thing that happens so no prior code would affect it

```
rD<- rsDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", browser="firefox", port=3004L, verbose =F)
```

And here is the error message

```
Selenium message:Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
Build Info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-92-94', ip: '172.31.92.94', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:'5.8.0-1042-aws'. java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace:

Could not open firefox browser.
Client error message:
Summary: UnkownError
Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to get a Selenium driver working via firefox or a via a different driver

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to put the shiny app in a docker and use an existing selenium docker image to create a selenium server in another container. Here is a repository on how to do this: https://github.com/danlooo/shiny-selenium